# Import .h.in header file in c

Tags: c, cmake, header, autoconf

Can I know how to import XXX.h.in header file in .c project file. Is there anything needs to be done for XXX.h.in with cmake before importing?

Comment: Mostly you write `#include “XXX.h”`.

Comment: #include "XXX.h" is not working for XXX.h.in header file. there are #cmakedefine preprocessing directive in XXX.h.in

Comment: That means there's an expectation that this file is converted before you build any file including `XXX.h` (whether it's included directly or indirectly). [`configure_file(XXX.h.in XXX.h)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) would be the logic used in a cmake project (probably with the exact file paths being different).